# Problems linking .o library files together into a shared object

Tags: c++, linux, boost, gcc, linker

I am working on a collection of reusable libraries that need to be made available both as static libraries (.a & .lib) and as dynamic libraries (.so & .dll).

I want dependency management for the dynamic libraries to be as simple as possible (you only take one dynamic library for each bit of functionality that you need), so all of the functional dependencies that each dynamic library has are actually statically linked into it. Thus, the dynamic libraries offer their functionality to downstream clients dynamically, but their upstream dependencies are satisfied statically.

The upshot of all this is that all of my static libraries need to be compiled with -fPIC so that their code is suitable for linkage into a shared library. The same goes for any third-party library that we use. It has to be a static library, compiled with -fPIC.

(I could, I suppose, build both PIC and non-PIC variants of my libraries - but I really do not want to compile the libraries a *third* time for each target platform -- twice is quite (more than) enough!).

So, here is my problem:

I have been trying to compile boost_system as a static library with -fPIC, but I am not sure if I am succeeding:

```
/b2 --build-type=complete variant=release link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static --layout=versioned --cxxflags=-fPIC
```

This build produces .a files as output, as expected. However, when I try to link the boost static library into one of my shared libraries, I start getting an error message that indicates that boost_system is not Position Independent Code:

```
.../dependencies/external/boost/1_54_0/stage/lib/linux_x86_64/libboost_system-gcc46-s-1_54.a(error_code.o): 
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

However, I have (attempted) to build boost with -fPIC. Is there any test that I can use to determine if libboost_system is actually PIC code? I.e. if the problem is with building boost - or with linking it to my application.

Comment: I'm confused by your use of the word `static` in the title and text of your question; static libraries don't need *position-independent code*.

Comment: I have reworded the question both to make it clearer, and also to reflect my improved understanding of the problem (I was making a n00b mistake and confusing "relocatable" with "Position Independent").

Comment: OK, that error message references a static library (`.a` file) which won't have been compiled with `-fPIC`...

Comment: I thought that you could compile static libraries with -fPIC. I am doing this because I am working on a bunch of reusable modules that need to be made available both as static libraries (.a & .lib) and as dynamic libraries (.so & .dll). I want dependency management for the dynamic libraries to be as simple as possible, so each of the dynamic libraries has all of it's dependencies statically linked into it. As a result, all of my static libraries are compiled with -fPIC so that as well as standing on their own as static libraries, they can also be linked into .so libraries as required.

Comment: Look at the build log and see if the offending file was really compiled with -fPIC.

Comment: I am currently doing just that ... although not too familiar with b2 & Jam -- but looks like you are right -- cxxflags are not going through to the compiler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem can be solved by removing the command line option "runtime-link=static" which enables static linking of the C++ runtime libraries. Since you are building a dynamic shared library object, you want to avoid this behavior, especially if clients are to link to your library from different Linux OS configurations. However, the option "link=static" is ok and should remain.